# how to redirect to home page from Servlet to JSP with Angular UI

Tags: angularjs, servlets

I have an AngularJs UI login page and I'm posting the username and password details to a Servlet to validate, and when I'm returning back I'm using `sendRedirect` from Servlet but it's not working.  Here is my sample code

In Servlet:

```
req.sendRedirect("NewFile.jsp");
```

It is displaying content inside NewFile.jsp within the login page itself instead of redirecting to NewFile.jsp

[image: Sample Error]

I have tried using "$window.location.href" inside AngularJs code but that itself didnt forward to home page.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Acording of what you said in the comment of the bounty, I have to say that having everything in only one controller sounds like a bad idea, for more information about this and naming conventions go to [Naming conventions and best practices](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide)

According to your question, maybe you need to give more details of the problem, it's not clear.

Have you tried to use $location module?
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

You can use de .path() module to redirect.

```
$location.path('#!/');
```

That will redirect you to the home page.

Comment: I myself solved this issue. I missed to provide a dot(.) before the url while assigning using window.location.href. I have used location.path but it didnt work earlier. thanks